# Привязка контроллеров к USB-портам

Tags: linux, usb, микроконтроллеры

Имеются два идентичных конторллера для управления шаговыми двигателями, подключенные по USB. Если подключать их при работающей ОС, то первый подключенный вешается на /dev/USB0, а второй на /dev/USB1.

Как сделать так, чтобы при старте системы первый контроллер всегда вешался на /dev/USB0, а второй на /dev/USB1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Попробуйте создать правила для Ваших контроллеров через udev.

> Каждый раз при подключении или
> отключении устройства ядро посылает
> событие uevent, которое информирует
> udev о произошедших изменениях. Демон
> udev считывает правила для своей
> работы из каталога /etc/udev/rules.d/
> единожды при своем запуске и затем
> хранит их в памяти.
>
> Каждое полученное событие сравнивается
> с набором загруженных правил. С
> помощью правил можно добавлять
> специфичные для окружения опции,
> создавать символические ссылки на
> создаваемый файл устройства или
> указать программу, запускаемую после
> того как файл устройства будет создан.
> События ядра uevents от драйверов
> устройств передаются через сокет ядра
> netlink.

Нампример, [здесь](http://igorka.com.ua/2010-03-24/znakomstvo-s-udev-v-ubuntu/) рассказывается, как создаются правила, но думаю, без труда найдете еще с десяток разных примеров и инструкций. Надеюсь, это то, что нужно! :)